# Type conversion to UInt8 [] from UInt8 gives an error

Tags: ios, objective-c, struct, type-conversion

I've defined a struct like so:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    UInt8  a;
    UInt16 b;
    UInt8  c[15];
} myStruct;
```

When I try to get value

```
UInt8  c = packet->c;
```

I receive the following error

> Incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'UInt8' (aka 'unsigned char') with an expression of type 'UInt8 [15]

What type do I need to cast to in order to compile? I have tried adding [15] subscript in different places and could not solve it. Also an explanation of what `[15]` means in `UInt8  c[15];`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `packet` is declared as `myStruct packet;`. If so, `packet->c` is an array of `UInt8`, you can store up to 15 items in this member. That's why you cannot assign it's value to a single `UInt8`. Replace `UInt8 c = packet->c;` with `UInt8* c = packet->c;`. To get the first `c`'s item use the following code: `UInt8 firstC = c[0];`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.How could I assign value to struct member `c`?  When I try  `myStruct.c = value;` I get the following error `Array type 'UInt8 [15]' is not assignable`. But I cn assign values to single `UInt8`'s.

Comment: Please look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57659851/how-to-pack-struct-with-a-byte-array

Comment: @AnonProgrammer Left a comment for you in this post.