# How to pack struct with a byte array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, pack

Im trying to pack data that resembles the following struct. **Ultimately this needs to be of type `NSData`.**

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    UInt8  a;
    UInt8  b;
    UInt8  c[17];
} myStruct;
```

If I try the following I get an error when assigning value to `c`.

```
myStruct str = {};
str.a = 1;
str.c = aByteArray; // `Array UInt8 [17] is not assignable.`
```

**How can pack data by either assigning values to `myStruct` or constructing its equivalent using `output`?**
    I think the following implementation would work for first 2 octets, but not the last array of 17 `UInt8's`, that also needs padding for last 2 octets. One problem looks like Im not actually assigning last 17 octets in a single array, so parser wouldn't succeed.

```
UInt8 a = 1;
UInt8 b = 0b00001111;

UInt8 output[] = {};
int idx = 0;
output[idx++] = a;
output[idx++] = b;
// add each
for (int i=0; i<15; i++) {
    // otherByteArray == UInt[15]
    output[idx++] = otherByteArray[i];
}
UInt8 padding = 0xAA;
output[idx++] = padding;
output[idx++] = padding;
```

**Update** 
This implementation seems to work, except the byteArrays do not match after the 8th index.. when they should, except for the padding.

```
    // Unpack
    Packet *packet = (Packet *)request.value.bytes;
    if (packet) {
        UInt8  a = packet->a;
        UInt8  b = packet->b;
        UInt8 *c = packet->c;

        for (int i=0; i<15; i++) {
            NSLog(@"c[%d]: %hhu", i, c[i]);
        }

        // Pack
        UInt8 output[20] = {};
        NSUInteger idx = 0;
        // packet num
        UInt8 a = a + 1;
        memcpy(&output[idx], &a, sizeof a);
        idx += sizeof a;
        // b
        UInt8 b = 0b01001111;
        memcpy(&output[idx], &b, sizeof b);
        idx += sizeof b;

        // c
        UInt8 result[17] = {};
        for (int i=0; i<15; i++) {
            result[i] = c[i];
        }
        UInt8 padding = 0xAA;
        result[15] = padding;
        result[16] = padding;
        memcpy(&output[idx], &result, sizeof result);
        idx += sizeof result;

        NSData *outputData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&output length:idx];

        ResponsePacket *response = (ResponsePacket *)outputData.bytes;
        UInt8 *responseC = response->c;

        for (int i=0; I<17; i++) {
            NSLog(@"responseC[%d]: %hhu", i, responseC[i]);
        }
```

Comment: The expression `UInt8 output[] = {};` should be rejected by your compiler. The array size is not specified. If your compiler accepts this and builds a zero-sized array `output` your code will overwrite some data (stack/heap/global data) where `output` is allocated.

Comment: The language `C` doesn't support assignment of an array. You need to copy byte by byte. This can be done using the function `memcpy`. Take care for size checks to avoid access out of bounds.

Comment: @harper can you please show an example of how you would construct NSData containing `UInt8`'s and arrays of `Uint8`'s? There different types so I can't seem to pack them together in a single byte array, which I can then convert to NSData.

Comment: @harper If the array is part of a struct you can actually use assignments. But of course this is assignment of struct, not of array. ;-) Behind the scene the compiler will probably just call `memcpy()`.

Comment: Are we talking about `C` or `objective-C` here?

Comment: @thebusybee `C`

Comment: @harper Please see updated implementation

Comment: Your update clearly shows that this is not `C`.

Comment: @thebusybee you’re right. I thought I was leveraging c functions and wasn’t limited to obj-c, and in addition to harpers implication. The byte arrays do not match even though they should up until last 2 octets. From looking at the  code, could you tell why this might be?

Comment: No, I don't see an obvious error. Did you step through your code with a debugger? I always found watch views very helpful.

Comment: @thebusybee fixed it

Comment: Now you could put your fix in an answer for the next visitors. :-)

Comment: @AnonProgrammer How did you fix the problem?

Comment: @thebusybee the problem was that I wasn't checking the size of `value` from initial `request` so I ended up adding zeros to the byteArray, when I needed more padding. But that confuses me since app didn't crash for trying to accessing value at index out of range. Guess not out of range since It had a predefined size.

Comment: Again: Please put your fix in an answer and mark it, you are allowed to answer your own question. So this question will be listed as answered and others with a same or similar problem find the solution right away without having to dig down in the comments.